# Avoid hardcoded font names in storyboards - UIFont name alias

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, uifont

**Is it possible to create an alias to a font that can be used inside storyboards?**

I have many storyboards that references to variants of [Orgovan-Rounded-Web](https://typekit.com/fonts/orgovan/details/orgovan-brush). Recently I had to change to another font. It was a lot of places I had to change the font. This could be less painful, if controlled from a single place.

I use this helper function when creating the font programmatically:

```
extension UIFont {
    static func clientName1_semiBold(_ size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        guard let font = UIFont(name: "Orgovan-Rounded-Web-SemiBold", size: size) else {
            fatalError("Font is supposed to be bundled with app")
        }
        return font
    }
}
```

In storyboards, one way to do the same in, could be use [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) to rename the ttf font from `Orgovan-Rounded-Web-SemiBold` to `clientName1-SemiBold` and refer to this name in the storyboards. I guess this violates the font copyrights.

**Do you use fontforge, or use hardcoded fontnames everywhere, or a better approach?**

Comment: Do you specifically ***need*** to see the exact font in your Storyboard? Or would a "placeholder" font do the job? If so, you can use `UIAppearance` at runtime. Alternatively, if you subclass your labels you can use IBDesignable to see the font changes while designing in your Storyboard.

Comment: Subclassing labels and using IBDesignable sounds like a good solution. With a placeholder font, it can be difficult to compare the storyboard with the design.